# Automatization Java AWT applet

Tags: java, applet, automation, awt, ui-automation

I need to automate my java application. I work with Selenium, but in this case it doesn't recognize elements of GUI. We use Java AWT of 2000. Can you help me with choosing right automation tool. I worked with AutoIT, but it is not the best variant to my application.

Comment: You want to automate the testing of your applet? Do you need some integration testing?

Comment: Of course, but it was the next step of process of automatization